# Trying to perform ADF pipeline logging in App Insights using Custom Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-application-insights

Can anyone help me with how to log each pipeline activity in App Insights. Can we do it from inside the pipeline or through any API calls?

Can custom activity in ADF call a class library in c#?

Comment: Have you tried any approach/effort? Share the blockers/errors that occurred during the implementation.

Comment: There is a custom activity in ADF-I want to know if we can call a c# code from it. So far I only got reference for python code.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a custom activity in ADF-I want to know if we can call a c# code from it. So far I only got reference for python code.

Yes, you can use **Custom activity** to execute C# code from ADF. If you have code to log the activity details, you can make use of Custom activity.

Go through this [blog](https://blog.devgenius.io/run-your-net-code-in-azure-data-factory-using-azure-batch-ecd2494c16f2) by @[Afzal Muhammad](https://muafzal.medium.com/?source=post_page-----ecd2494c16f2--------------------------------) to understand more about this.

Or as an alternative you can use **Azure functions also of C# type**. After building the Azure function with your code and call it using http trigger from ADF **Azure function** activity.

**My Sample:**

[image]

Comment: So how can we pass parameters to this C# code in cmd- I want to use the code to show custom logs of each activity's success or failure so would need to pass details like ADf name ,run ID etc.

Comment: For custom activity, Follow the blog that I have given above. There is enough information in that regarding your ask.